# TaskStackBuilder#startActivities() NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, taskstackbuilder

I have a crash that keeps occurring on 4.4.2 and 4.4.3 devices (although I'm not sure this is an API issue), where in some `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` the following code causes a `NullPointerException` somewhere deep inside the `startActivities` call.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
            .addParentStack(SomeActivity.class)
            .addNextIntent(intent)
            .startActivities();
```

I have tried testing to see whether the context was null, however, the Intent instantiation would've caught that. It might also be worth noting that this application is using `Parse Push`. 
The crash log for this crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.app.android.receiver.PushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2567)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivities(ActivityManagerNative.java:4494)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivitiesAsUser(Instrumentation.java:1496)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivities(Instrumentation.java:1458)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivities(ContextImpl.java:1465)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivities(ContextWrapper.java:350)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivities(ContextWrapper.java:350)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatJellybean.startActivities(ContextCompatJellybean.java:26)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivities(ContextCompat.java:105)
       at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:325)
       at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:301)
       at com.example.app.android.receiver.PushReceiver.routePush(PushReceiver.java:59)
       at com.example.app.android.receiver.PushReceiver.onPushOpen(PushReceiver.java:35)
       at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:108)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2552)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: I'm running in to basically the same thing. Seeing it only on 4.4.2 and 4.4.4

Comment: Any luck? Did you solve it?

Comment: I did not, unfortunately.

Comment: also seen only on Samsung so far - 4.4.2 and 4.4.4. I suspect they are using a rewritten version of `ActivityManagerNative`, because the line numbers in my crashes don't match up to the AOSP code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this problem as I have a suspicion that this might be a bug specific to 4.4.* devices. As an alternative, I replaced my use of the `TaskStackBuilder` with creating my activities via `PendingIntent.getActivities`. In my case, this provided equivalent functionality and it was a straightforward replacement. Perhaps you might find it useful as well.

```
final Intent parentIntent = new Intent(context, ParentActivity.class);
parentIntent.putExtra(ParentActivity.EXTRA, extraValue);

final Intent childIntent = new Intent(context, ChildActivity.class);
childIntent.putExtra(ChildActivity.EXTRA, extraChildValue);
childIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

final Intent[] intents = new Intent [] {parentIntent, childIntent};
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, INTENT_REQUEST_CODE, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

pendingIntent.send();
```

Comment: Awesome workaround. Will throw it in the next update for this app as an alternative for API 19, will report back with findings.

Comment: Been running this in production for a bit now and haven't run into any issues with. Great stuff @daniel