# App crashes on building back stack

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building in my `IntentService` a back stack. I am receiving crash reports from Kitkat devices.

My code is very simple and I don't know what could be the reason. I have a stacktrace but it's not getting me anywhere. Anyone experienced something like this?

```
    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent != null) {
            val articleIntent = intentFor<ArticleActivity>()
            articleIntent.putExtras(intent)
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addNextIntent(intentFor<DrawerActivity>()).addNextIntent(articleIntent).startActivities()
        }
    }
```

Exception from Crashlytics

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivities(ActivityManagerNative.java:4473)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivitiesAsUser(Instrumentation.java:1496)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivitiesAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1417)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivitiesAsUser(ContextWrapper.java:356)
       at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:221)
       at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:232)
       at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:208)
       at se.omni.gcm.OpenArticleService.onHandleIntent(OpenArticleService.kt:27)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: what is code for this line `IntentService.java:65`

Comment: @KaranMer it is `ServiceHandler` class from `IntentService` implementation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TaskStackBuilder#startActivities() NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754754/taskstackbuilderstartactivities-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found similar question on the SO [TaskStackBuilder#startActivities() NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754754/taskstackbuilderstartactivities-nullpointerexception) with answer that satisfy me. Since I started a bounty, I cannot close or delete this question.

Comment: Glad to see That .Move ahead . `NullPointerException` Is Culprit